# Why do we need a consumer and supplier functions in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I tried to read on the new `java.util.function` `Consumer`, `Supplier` and `Function`.

I didn't understand why do we need them, what was the problem and what they solved?

Could you please give me an example of use without those API and with the new API and what is solved?

Comment: Do you mean the 2 interfaces `Consumer` and `Supplier`? If so, did you read their JavaDocs? And did you read about lambdas?

Comment: Yes I meant 2 interfaces Consumer and Supplier I read the javadocs but I didn't understand why they solved

Comment: They are common [functional interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html#package.description) intended to be used as targets for [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: @ Jesper- what do you meant   targets for lambda expression ?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you assume that they have to be more complex than they are.

They are designed to be super simple pieces of code which don't do very much in themselves, but as pieces of code you can pass to a library which can use these pieces of code.

This example prints 100 UUIDs using a Supplier and a Consumer

```
Stream.generate(UUID::random) // <<< Supplier<UUID>
      .limit(100)
      .forEach(System.out::println); // <<< Consumer<UUID>
```

A longer example is

```
Supplier<UUID> uuidSupplier = UUID::random;
Consumer<UUID> uuidConsumer = System.out::println;
Stream.generate(uuidSupplier)
      .limit(100)
      .forEach(uuidConsumer);
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand how the supplier and consumer is explained in this example

Comment: @user1365697 A `Supplier` solves the problem of when you need to be able to tell a library how to create an object as required and a `Consumer` solves the problem of telling a library about an action you want to perform for each object.

Comment: if I don't use Supplier and Consumer how the example should look like ? in the example you didn't use them so I little bit confused

Comment: @user1365697 I think I see the problem, I did use them, perhaps the longer example helps.